export json output to environment variable missing commas in Bash
[{
"Availab]ilityZone": "ap-east-1a" 
  "Description": "AWS_FOO" 
  "Groups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO" 
      "GroupId": "sg-AWS_FOO"
    } 
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO" 
      "GroupId": "sg-AWS_FOO"
    }
  ] 
 }
 {
"Availab]ilityZone": "ap-east-1a" 
  "Description": "AWAWS_FOOAWS_FOO" 
  "Groups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO-eAWS_FOOAWS_FOO" 
      "GroupId": "sAWS_FOO"
    } 
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO" 
      "GroupId": "AWS_FOO"
    }
  ] 
}]

I am tring to write a automation script that required to use aws cli to find the values,
NETWORK_INTERFACE=$(aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="${VPC_ID}" --output json | jq -r '.NetworkInterfaces[]')

However, when I echo $NETWORK_INTERFACE the output will missing all commas "," , make it not a valid json format and cannot use jq to further action
I tried using IFS, sed but the result is not what I expected
My expected output is valid json like
[{
"Availab]ilityZone": "ap-east-1a",
  "Description": "AWS_FOO" ,
  "Groups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO" ,
      "GroupId": "sg-AWS_FOO",
    } ,
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO" ,
      "GroupId": "sg-AWS_FOO",
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "Availab]ilityZone": "ap-east-1a",
  "Description": "AWAWS_FOOAWS_FOO",
  "Groups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO-eAWS_FOOAWS_FOO",
      "GroupId": "sAWS_FOO",
    },
    {
      "GroupName": "AWS_FOO",
      "GroupId": "AWS_FOO",
    }
  ] 
}]


Your expected output isn't valid JSON...

Include input json text for those of us who don't do aws?

there should be a array to contain the object, I updated it

.NetworkInterfaces returns the array, .NetworkInterfaces[] returns the elements of the array. Similar question from just a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78401284/112968

Your first code block cannot be generated by jq. Either you get square brackets with commas or no brackets and no commas.

Did you double-quote the variable reference (i.e. echo "$NETWORK_INTERFACE" instead of just echo $NETWORK_INTERFACE) and/or change IFS? Failing to double-quote and changing IFS are both invitations to problems; doing both basically guarantees problems. shellcheck.net will point out at least some of these common mistakes.

This should do the trick.
#!/bin/bash

VPC_ID=vpc-05ae0495871281736

NETWORK_INTERFACE=$(aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="${VPC_ID}" --output json | jq -r '[.NetworkInterfaces[] | {AvailabilityZone, Description, Groups}]')

echo $NETWORK_INTERFACE

Substitute your own value for VPC_ID.
Based on your sample output I have filtered out the fields AvailabilityZone, Description and Groups.
The output from the script will just be a single line of valid JSON. You can prettify that by passing it through jq ..
For example:
[
  {
    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-2c",
    "Description": "test",
    "Groups": [
      {
        "GroupName": "VNC",
        "GroupId": "sg-030848ac470abe56f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-2c",
    "Description": "",
    "Groups": [
      {
        "GroupName": "MOSH",
        "GroupId": "sg-06dff26a1939d90d7"
      },
      {
        "GroupName": "http(s)",
        "GroupId": "sg-048d4d5554f4a7da6"
      }
    ]
  }
]


